# Finding a Taylor Series about some $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I want to find the Taylor series representation of the function $f(z) = \frac{z+3}{2-z}$ about the point $z_0=i$. But I am struggling to figure out how to write this about a complex number. So consider

$$f(z) = \frac{z+3}{2-z} = -1 +\cdot\frac{5}{2-z} = -1+ 5 \cdot \frac{1}{2-z}$$

$$ = -1 + 5 \cdot \frac{1}{2-i+i-z} = -1 + 5 \cdot \frac{1}{2-i-(z-i)} = -1 +5 \cdot  \frac{2-i}{2-i} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{2-i}}{1-\frac{z-i}{2-i}} = ???$$

I don't think it would be heard to find the Taylor series for this function about some real number. But the fact that we need to expand about $z_0 = i$ is throwing me off. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I have found that

$$f(z) = \frac{z+3}{2-z} = -1 +\cdot\frac{5}{2-z} = -1+ 5 \cdot \frac{1}{2-z}$$

$$ = -1 + 5 \cdot \frac{1}{2-i+i-z} = -1 + 5 \cdot \frac{1}{2-i-(z-i)}$$

$$= -1 +5\cdot \frac{1}{2-i} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{z-i}{2-i}} =-1 + \frac{5}{2-i} \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Big( \frac{z-i}{2-i}\Big)^n$$

$$= -1 + \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{5}{(2-i)^{n+1}}(z-i)^n$$

Does anyone have any advice on how to get that $-1$ inside the sum? Merely changing our indices won't work since the first term in the series is $\frac{5}{2-i}$. Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-i}{2-i}}=\sum_n\Big(\frac{z-i}{2-i}\Big)^n$ for all $z$ with $\Big|\frac{z-i}{2-i}\Big|<1$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I have updated the problem. I now only need to get the lingering $-1$ inside the series if possible. Thoughts?

Comment: do the reverse: pull the 0 term out of the sum so you get $1 + i + \sum_{n=1}^\infty$

Comment: The $n=0$ term, I mean. Since it doesn't fit the pattern of the rest of them, leaving it outside the sum sign is fine.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I see. So there might not be a way to write $f(z)$ as a closed series with no lingering additions on the exterior?

Comment: Correct, but there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @eyeballfrog oh I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it as $1-i+ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5}{(2-i)^{n+1}}(z-i)^n$. That's a valid series; you have a formula that works for $a_n$ for $a>0$ and another formula for $a=0$, but series don't need to have an easily written formula.